# On removing a tag from ngTagsInput, the input field will get focused automatically. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I think [this](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/src/tags-input.js#L343) code is having some problem. Because when I click on a tag to remove it, the click event will propagate to host div which results in focusing the input box.

Is there a way or any attribute that will prevent the input box from getting focused on removing a tag?